# Can I use alt = [Next] to gather reviews from each page?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Once again, trying to get help for a little bit of university research. I am trying to figure out a way to scrape all of the reviews for each movie without manually writing each url and iterating over it in a set.

So, I'm trying to find the "Next" button and use that to guide how many pages of reviews to gather. In theory I would like it to stop on the last page of reviews since there would be no "Next" button on the last page. So if there are three pages of reviews, it would stop getting the reviews on the third page.

To keep it simple, this is just some of the code I have now, but it only gets the first page of reviews.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
           'Headers': "http://www.imdb.com/"}

count = 0
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182408/reviews?start=' + str(count)
r = s.get(url).content
page = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

cj = s.cookies
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(cj)

nv = soup.find("input", value="nv_sr_fn")["value"]

hidden_data = dict(ref_=nv)

s.post(url, data=hidden_data, headers=headers)

important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')


for div in important.findAll("div"):
    for p in div.findAll("p"):
        p.decompose()

for small in important.findAll("small", text=re.compile("review useful:")):
    div = small.parent
    user_id = div.select_one("a[href^=/user/ur]")["href"].split("r/")[1].rstrip("/")
    rating = div.select_one("img[alt*=/10]")
    print(user_id, rating["alt"] if rating else "N/A")
    print(div.findAll("small"))
    print(div.find_next("h2").text.strip())
    print(div.find_next("a").text.strip())
    print(div.find_next("p").text.strip())

for td in important.findAll('td'):
    for a in td.findAll('a'):
        for img in a.findAll('img', alt=True):
            if img['alt'] == "[Next]":
                count = +10

            else:
                break
```

This is the last review I get which is on the first page.

```
ur0186755 1/10
[<small>11 out of 20 people found the following review useful:</small>, <small>from South Texas</small>, <small>27 March 1999</small>]
One of the stupidest films ever made...

Before I start to tear apart this movie, mark you--I LOVE THE SCARLET
PIMPERNEL. That story is one of the best romantic adventures ever written.
The movie staring Jane Grey is very good and the musical on Broadway is
the
hottest thing there. So, I thought when I heard that this film was coming
out that it would be great since it was a BBC film.To my surprise, it was a weak, totally stupid story that UTTERLY failed in
capturing the gorgeous tale.There were no exciting escapes with daring disguises. There was no deep
love
that made your heart flutter as Percy left the room and Marguerite sighed
as
her husband was leaving her again.All it had was a confusing plot and a lot of out-of-the-blue sex and
violence.Sink me! What a horrible movie!
```

Any tips on how I can go about gathering reviews from each page besides manually putting the urls in a set and iterating over them. Or do I have to do that? Thanks very much.

Comment: From the [IMDB terms of use](http://www.imdb.com/conditions): "Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you are not violating any [IMDB terms of use](http://www.imdb.com/conditions) and staying on the legal side. You might better use the IMDB API instead of falling down to web-scraping.

---

To answer your question, I would make an endless loop with a break condition relying on the presence of the `Next` link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
        'Headers': "http://www.imdb.com/"
    }

    page = 0
    while True:
        url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182408/reviews?start=' + str(page)
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

        important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')
        for title in important.find_all("h2"):
            print(title.get_text())

        # break if no Next button present
        if not soup.find("img", alt="[Next]"):
            break

        page += 10
```

Prints 30 lines of review titles (10 lines per page).

Comment: Is there any way I could then do that for multiple movies? This works great for one movie, but as soon as I try to put multiple movies in a set, it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep going until the *img* with the alt is not on the page, you can get the next page *href* by calling .parent on the *img* tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

def parse(soup):
    important = soup.find("div", id='tn15content')
    for small in important.find_all("small", text=re.compile("review useful:")):
        div = small.parent
        user_id = div.select_one("a[href^=/user/ur]")["href"].split("ur")[1].rstrip("/")
        rating = div.select_one("img[alt*=/10]")
        yield user_id, rating["alt"] if rating else "N/A"


def get_all_pages(start):
    base = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082158/"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(start).content)
    for tup in parse(soup):
        yield tup

    for nxt in iter(lambda: soup.find("img", alt="[Next]"), None):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urljoin(base, nxt.parent["href"])).content)
        for tup in parse(soup):
            yield tup


for uid, rat in get_all_pages(start):
    print(uid, rat)
```

You might also want to consider adding a sleep between each request or better again to use [IMDbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/)